# Python: use of r" " and + token in re.sub() function

Tags: python, regex

I am not able to understand what the `re.sub()` function does in Python. I have read the documentation and other StackOverflow posts, but none of them clearly explains the `re.sub()` function. Can someone help me understand? For example:

```
def _strip(s):
    return re.sub(r'[\W_]+', '', s)
```

I know that this function removes non-letter characters from a word. For example

```
_strip('Hi there!') == 'Hi there'
```

1. But why does this function use `''` after the `r` tag?
2. And why is the `+` symbol not used within the square brackets after the `r` tag?

Comment: Are you comfortable with regex in python ?

Comment: This isn't a general Python function, it's specific to the "regular expression" (`re`) module, and is covered in [the documentation for that module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub). If you don't understand regex syntax, see e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html.

Comment: @laurent - yes to some extent

Answer (score 1):

- `r`: a raw string.
- `''`: the replacement
- `+`: one or more of the preceeding
- `[\W_]+`: one or more of `\W` or `_`

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub where all this is explained.